# jQuery hide\show rows in table via data attribute

Tags: jquery, rows, show-hide

I have a table, `#thetable` which contains rows from a database. Above the table I have a `button` 'diesel' which I want when click to hide or show rows whose data attributes are diesel, so each row has a `data-attribute` that is either `diesel` or `petrol`. However when I click it the lines to not disappear.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function clickDiesel() {
  $("tr[data-fuel=diesel]").css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-right: 1em" onclick="clickDiesel()">
  diesel 
  <span style="color: Green">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
  </span>
</button>

<table id="thetable">
  <tr data-fuel="diesel">
    <td>diesel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-fuel="petrol">
    <td>petrol</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I placed your code in a runnable snippet where it appears to work fine. Could you please check the console for errors elsewhere in your code. Also - is the data in the table added to the page *after* the page itself loads? Via AJAX for example. Also, as an aside, I'd suggest removing the outdated `on*` event attribute and attaching your event handlers through unobtrusive JS instead.

Comment: Try `.hide()` instead of changing visibility.  Visibility hidden still takes up the same space when rendered and this may be the causing the issue of "do not disappear".

Comment: Great that works perfectly and I did use .hide().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with

```
<script>
function clickDiesel()
{
    $("tr[data-fuel='diesel']").css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: Tried it but they are not disappearing